# X-ray spectra and the presenence of L, M,.. etc series?

Tags: spectroscopy, x-rays

Consider the diagram below:
[image]
([Public Domain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:XrtSpectrum.jpg))

On diagrams like why are the $L$, $M$, and so on series not present? And is their any way to make them present e.g. reduce the tube voltage etc.

Comment: Where do you expect the L lines to appear? Then note the difference between the 'Unfiltered' line and the measured Bremsstrahlung line.

Comment: @JonCuster ye I actually thought about this after I asked the question. The L lines would appear on the unfiltered line but are filtered out. Nevertheless on the unfiltered line I have seem images within only the K and L series shown but none higher - is their some interaction affects going on here as well as filtering?

Comment: Taking the numbers at face value (kinda), consider the K lines to be from something like Re (k-alpha of 59/61keV, k-beta at 69keV). The L lines are between 8.5 and 11.6 keV. So, much lower energy, not to be seen here. The M lines are, well, even lower in energy.

Comment: There is always filtering: the glass (or other window material) of the source, the air, the window of the detector. And then there are intentional filters.

Comment: @JonCuster If we were to consider a theoretical case where we some how manged to remove all filtering, would all the series K, L, M,..., up to the second to last shell occupied by the electrons be visible and if so how would their intensities compare?

Comment: @Pieter see my above comment.

Comment: Intensities will be much lower even without any filtering because the competing Auger decay is more important for orbitals with less binding energy. But one can observe K-lines and L-lines in the same spectrum, I can try to find an example.

Comment: @Pieter Thanks for your comment. Would the bombarding electrons (if used) interact more strongly with the inner shell electrons then the outer shell - which would also decrease the intensity?

Comment: Excitation by electrons or x-rays should not affect relative intensities. I found a spectrum with K and L emission from selenium. Raw spectrum, not normalized for detection efficiency; probably most of the Se K rays go right through the detector. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/235881093_fig2_EDS-spectrum-of-purified-Se-NPs-Selenium-X-ray-emission-peaks-are-labeled-Strong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figure seems to be a cartoon, not a real spectrum. And/or it is not of a single element. The pair of lines at higher energy look like $L_\alpha$ and $L_\beta$ but then it is an element with impossibly high $Z$. The other pair of lines has an intensity ratio typical of $K_\alpha$ and $K_\beta$ but then the weaker one ($K_\beta$) should be at higher photon energy.

Tungsten is a common material for x-ray anodes in this range. The W $K_{\alpha 1}$ energy is at 59.31 keV and $K_{\beta 1}$ is at 67.23 keV. But maybe it also shows the $K_{\alpha 2}$ line at 58.0 keV? In that case the alpha1-alpha2 splitting is not to scale.

The point of the cartoon seems to be that one needs electrons with at least the $1s$ binding energy to excite the $K_\alpha$ lines. So 60 keV is not enough to get the K emission lines of tungsten.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer to this question is mixed up in the answers and comments, and since I have found some other points concerning this question I thought I would 'summarize' them in this answer.

The intensity of a line depends on 4 main things:

**1. The Affect of filtering**

(Thanks to Jon Cluster and Pieter for explaining) Filtering can be put in place deliberately or as a natural consequence of the apparatus used e.g. the glass window, air etc. Although this filtering can be determined by the filter used, as a rule higher energies x-rays (and therefore K-series) tend to be filtered less.

**2. The Affect of Ionization Cross-section**

(See reference {1}). The ionization cross-section, $\sigma(E)$, determines the probability that if you send in a beam of electrons (energy $E$) you get an ionization. The ionization cross section follows the following rough pattern.

- Increases rapidly above $E_{ion}$ (the ionization energy)
- Reaches a maximum at $E\sim 3E_{ion}$
- Decreases slowly and monotonically above there.

**3. Probability the vacant site will be filled by a given outer state.**

(see reference {2}) Let us say we have a vacant site in the $K$ then the intensity of the lines (ignoring other factors) formed by transitions to this line is proportional to the statistical wight $2J+1$ of the starting level. This is known as the 'sum rule'.

**4. Fluorescence Yield**

(Thanks to Pieter, see also reference {2}) The probability of emitting characteristic radiation is balanced by that of emitting an augar electron instead. In all cases expect that of the K-series the probability of emitting an augar electron is much greater then that of emitting an x-ray reducing their intensities. This can be quantified in something called the 'fluorescence yield' defined as the ratio of the radiative probability, $\Gamma_r$, to the total transmission probability, $\Gamma_{tot}$:
$$\omega=\frac{\Gamma_r}{\Gamma_{tot}}$$

**Conclusion**

The above factors (and others such as detector efficiency etc.) determine the intensity of the lines and thus their presence in the spectrum.

**References**

{1} Bell, D.C. and Garratt-Reed, A.J., 2003. *Energy dispersive X-ray analysis in the electron microscope* (Vol. 49). Garland Science. ($\S$2.2)

{2} Verma, H.R., 2007. *Atomic and Nuclear Analytical Methods:  XRF, Mössbauer, XPS, NAA and Ion-Beam Spectroscopic Techniques*. Springer ($\S$1.3.2)

Answer (score -1):

The temperature may be high enough to strip most L electrons, while K electrons remain (assuming high-Z element). I'd say it somehow matches the value of 100 kV.

Now to obtain K lines that strong, you need other effects in your setup, such as non-thermal electrons. They could generate those high-energy lines, while not interfering much with the thermal emission.

Comment: The emission is not thermal, has nothing to do with temperature.